# How to write stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 that generates 3 million random no

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

How to write stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 that generates 3 million random no in two columns in integer datatype.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT TOP 3000000 
    ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) As RndCol1, 
    ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) AS RndCol2
FROM 
    sys.objects s1 
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2 
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s3
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s4
```

[You may want to check the actual distribution of these numbers using a chi-square test]

**UPDATE**: The randomness of these may not meet the chi-square distribution test. I would advise Testing in for your circumstances.

Comment: This is much faster than my CTE.  But a triple join on sys.objects gets to 421k rows on my system, but I guess you can join more as needed!

Comment: @Andomar: really? - I got 3 million on mine. I'll add another for good measure!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE, for example:

```
create procedure dbo.GiveMeRandomNumbers
as
    begin
    with qry as (
        select  CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT) as col1
        ,       CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT) as col2
        ,       0 as i
        union all
        select  CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT) as col1
        ,       CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT) as col2
        ,       i + 1 
        from    qry
        where   i < 3000000
    )
    select  col1, col2
    from    qry
    option  (maxrecursion 0)
    end
```

This uses `newid` because the `rnd` function will return the same result for each recursive application of the CTE.